# Windows RDP client connects to port 443, causing the connection to be delayed

Tags: firewall, remote-desktop, windows-server, gateway

I have a RDS setup which includes an RD host and a RD gateway, each one in a different server. I have the following configuration (for privacy ill use generic IPs):

| Server | IP | Ports | O.S. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rdgateway | 192.168.0.10 | TCP (SSL) 44300, UDP 3391 | Windows Server 2016 |
| rdhost | 192.168.0.11 | TCP 3389 | Windows Server 2016 |

When I connect from a MACOS client, connection works great and fast. On the other hand, when I use a Windows client, connection lasts 20 seconds more.

These are connection settings in the RD client:

| RD host connection | RD gateway options |
| --- | --- |
| 192.168.0.11 | https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY9Vs.png |

While analyzing RD gateway traffic with Wireshark, I noticed that my client sends a SYN packet to connect to port 443 (even though I specify 44300 in settings) and then receives 4x SYN TCP Retransmission packets.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtSUi.png

If I completely disable firewall in my RD gateway, connection works in <3s from a Windows client, but the 4 connection attempts to port 443 are still present, adding outgoing packets from port 443 in between:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4HJW.png

I've tried to create rules to allow all connections, both incoming and outgoing (simultaneously and separately), but it still works as if they did not exist.

It's a rare scenario, given that I don't specify to connect to port 443 at any point. The issue lies with the Windows RD client, as on macOS it connects correctly to port 44300 initially and works perfectly.